# Lucene.NET Performances Concerns with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, lucene.net

I'm currently developping a web site with asp.net that use Lucene.Net to perform fulltext queries.

The web site display a couple of data lists.

The problem is that i perform fulltext queries FOR EACH items displayed in the list which can be a performance issue.

So i wonder if i should "pre fulltext query" with a kind of Search Engine maybe with caching topology instead of performing fulltext queries on demand when items are displayed (queried)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend caching fulltext query results as they're generated.

As you loop through the items in the list, check a cache to see if you already have results.  If not, get the fulltext results and put them in the cache.